# Drop event in backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I'm trying to add a `drop` event in my backbone view but I can't get it right. Below is the code I'm using and you can also check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eLLmW/24/).

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        'drop .dropzone': 'drop'
    },

    drop: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Dropping');
    },

    initialize: function() {},

    render: function() {}
});

$(function() {
    var view = new View({
        el: $('.dropzone');
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your view's el == .dropzone then you should do

```
events: {
    'drop': 'drop'
},
```

if you specify just event type without selector it will listen to event on the view's root element - $('.dropzone') in this case.

The way you did it here would try to find .dropzone element among children of .dropzone element - and clearly it would fail to find this element at all

Comment: Stupid mistake by me but it doesn't work anyway, my browser just shows the image and no event is fired?

Comment: do you have a library to handle drop event?

Comment: no? I thought that was a built in event in backbone? Maybe I was wrong?

Comment: drop event is not supported by default - you can try something like https://github.com/gaarf/jquery.event.drag-drop or http://jquerypp.com/ or dunno - haven't tested these but I remember I had to extend jQuery some time ago to get file dnd to work with backbone

Comment: I'm currently building a web app in Backbone with drag and drop functionality and have found http://jqueryui.com/draggable/ works well.